# Broker Application Development: Find which flows my subflow belongs to

Tags: ibm-mq, messagebroker

I've handling some legacy applications running on WMB and am trying to work out how to find which main flows a particular subflow belongs to. Seems an obvious thing to be able to do but I can't seem to find it???? Grrrr

I'm using Broker Application Development 6.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The toolkit does support the feature in v7 I think - you can use the Impact Analysis to identify this.

I think there's a search string you can use... I used to have it saved somewhere. You basically want to search inside all of the .msgflow files as text / xml and find references to the name of your subflow file.

Comment: Impact Analysis looks like a big improvement. I'm still stuck with v6, but hopefully we'll upgrade to v7 this year.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the toolkit doesn't support this feature. My workaround is searching for the name of the subflow in all the msgflow files.